# Are these ferrite beads or fuses? Laptop MB, power section

Tags: power-supply, power, motherboard

This is a motherboard from ASUS G75VW laptop. What are these 3 parts? When I put the battery in the laptop, after several minutes it turns off and these parts are burnt. I had a second MB and replaced them, now use the laptop without the battery.

The parts are placed immediately after the power connector.

Maybe I should replace them with higher values, or what can you suggest?

[image]

Comment: Where is the photo?

Comment: Forgot it :) Here is it.

Answer (score 3):

The parts are ferrite beads. If they are burning up then something is horribly wrong on the other side of them (probably shorted MOSFETs and maybe worse).

Oops. Make that "definitely worse"- the ON Semi Schottky diode (probably) visible in your photo is obviously FUBAR.

You are not likely going to be able to fix this very easily given your current level of knowledge- take it to a repair person.

Comment: Can you suggest the replacements' characteristics?

Comment: You could measure the case size and if you know the current, pick a suitable replacement. If they measure almost a short from end to end they are still functional as conductors anyway (their purpose is just to reduce EMI). But other things are obviously wrong and replacing them can only cause additional damage at this point.

Comment: Replacement characteristics won't help. From croocked soldering it is obvious that somebody already tried to replace the parts. The problem is somewhere else that caused these parts to burn. Unless you determine where the actual problem is (short in some blown IC), replacement won't help.

Comment: As I wrote in my post, I replaced this parts and the laptop works now. They burn when I put the battery.

Comment: As I wrote above- there are SERIOUS PROBLEMS. The diode has a crater in the package where the die used to be. Do whatever you like, it's your laptop.

Comment: @RomanSimonyan,  then logically one must assume that this is the battery that causes (or facilitates) the issue. Did you try another battery? Did you check your battery in another known good laptop?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany thank you for your answers and your time. I am here to learn and experiment in electronics and it is great that people like you are willing to help. Sometimes, maybe I am not clear in my questions, but answers like "take it to repair service" or "do whatever you want" are not helping. If you can help me with my questions, it will be great. Wish you all the best.

Comment: @Ali Chen the story is a little bit longer... My laptop worked for several years and after BIOS update it was bricked. I had no tools then and tried to replace the chip with soldering iron. I damaged pcb pads. Then I ordered new board, placed it and laptop worked, but battery was not charging. After several hours laptop turned off. I opened and these parts were burnt. I replaced them and it was working for several days, then I decided to put the battery back and it turned off again after an hour.

Comment: I replaced burnt details again, these were last remaining from my old MB. The battery was working with old configuration and everything happened after new motherboard was used. So, I do not think it is the battery.

Comment: Now I have necessary tools and want to try some things. So I need to know what are these to order them and try :)

Comment: I have several newer laptops, electronics is my hobby, and I want to break some things. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since @SpehroPefhany pointed out that diode is shorted, maybe you can take the one off the old motherboard to replace it with.

Comment: @RomanSimonyan, This is not serious. You need to have full schematics to repair this board, because reverse engineering of 12/16-layer board would be quite challenging, and usually the whole logic around battery charging is quite convoluted. Just throw the board away and find something more useful to do.

Comment: I repaired my old MB PCB tracks and soldered these parts back there along with the BIOS chip. Everything works great. Thanks for help.